# How to stop authentication of host message from coming up.

Tags: bash, ssh

I am writing a script to log into multiple Cisco routers. I am running into and issue. This message pops up every time. "The authenticity of host 'x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)' cant be established RSA key fingerprint is X. Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

From everything I have read about this says this is normal for the first time sshing into it, but it should store the RSA key and no longer display this message. Is there anyway to stop this message from popping up?

Here is my code so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn ssh -l user x.x.x.x

sleep 3

expect "*word"

send "mypassword"
send \r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your ssh options:

```
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

Comment: or, @TylendelZollmann,  does the userID you're connecting from have a /home/userID/.ssh dir? If not try making that if you can. You should then see a file `known_hosts` appear there. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You! That did it, but now it gives the warning of permanently adding the router to the lists of known hosts. then goes to Password: and exits. Why is it not recognizing my send command for the password?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to avoid host key verification and not use `known_hosts` file for a particular remote machine, you can also add the following to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host remote_machine_ip
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` - Golbal configuration
`$HOME/.ssh/config` - User-specific configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can expect that prompt to occur, and actually answer it:

```
spawn ssh -l user x.x.x.x

expect {
    "connecting (yes/no)" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    "password:"           {send "mypassword\r"}
}
```

`exp_continue` basically acts as a loop so that you can keep waiting for the password prompt.
If the "connecting" prompt does not occur, no problem: expect will see the password prompt and carry on.